# Making second <select> validation required if first <select> set to some option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, select

How to make second select required for validation if 'yes' was selected in first?

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : articleEditForm.pnp.$invalid && !articleEditForm.pnp.$pristine }">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Working? (yes/no) *</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select class="form-control" name='pnp' id='pnp' ng-model="article.pnp" ng-options="o.value as o.option for o in items" required></select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : articleAddForm.idpnpgrupe.$invalid && !articleAddForm.idpnpgrupe.$pristine }">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Pnp grupa </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select class="form-control" name='idpnpgrupe' id='idpnpgrupe' ng-model="article.idpnpgrupe" ng-options="o.id as o.opis for o in catchpnpgrupe"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ng-required`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired) directive and define expression for input element. If expression is evaluated as `true`, `input` will be `required`

```
<select class="form-control" name='idpnpgrupe' id='idpnpgrupe' ng-model="article.idpnpgrupe" ng-options="o.id as o.opis for o in catchpnpgrupe" ng-required="article.pnp=='yes'"></select>
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_